# How to host expressjs application on cpanel shared hosting?

Tags: node.js, express, cpanel

I am trying to deploy my simple express application in shared hosting cpanel, but when I try to access my app it shows `Cannot GET /apps/api/`
Please see the screenshot to see my setup below:-
[image]

index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
var port=process.env.PORT?process.env.PORT:80;

app.get('/api', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "myexpress",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

After application creation, I run the **RUN NPM INSTALL** and then perform application restart
Please note that normal nodejs application works fine, I can access it, but when I try to host my app that uses expressjs framework, then I face the error. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

https://victoryflame.com/article/create-an-express-application-with-a2-hosting

This solution worked for me. **(copying solution from VictoryFlame's site)**

Lets go into our Setup Node.js app on CPanel, then we want to select the Application you want to host your Node.js app.

Next you want to create a package.json with the following information

```js
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My App",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "./node_modules/parcel-bundler/bin/cli.js public/index.js --out-dir public/dist"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "ejs": "~2.6.1",
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

In your nodejs hosting project, stop the app from running
Then, click Run NPM Install button. (you may have to refresh the page for the button to become active)

Let’s go back into our File Manager and back into root of the project we were working on. There, we want to create a new folder views with a file named index.ejs

Inside index.ejs, we want to put in the following

```html
<h1>Hello Node Express</h1>
```

Then we want to go into our app.js file in our root directory and replace everything inside it with the following

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


app.use('/a2nodejs/static', express.static('public'));

app.get('/a2nodejs', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

app.listen();
```

Now go back into Setup Node.js section and restart our hosting application

Go to the url of our project and you should see the html from our index.ejs being served

But what if we wanted our ejs file to have data that comes from our server.

To do that, go into your index.ejs file and replace Express from the following

## Hello Node Express

Now go to our application url and you should see our updated page